# Nesting error when trying to parse JSONfile

Tags: ruby, json, reddit

I'm trying to parse the JSON file of a Reddit thread with all it's comments. But when I try to parse the JSON I get a **"in `parse': nesting of 20 is too deep "** error.

Below is the code i use:

```
#require 'net/http'
#require 'rubygems'
#require 'json'

@response = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/sjm1z/what_is_your_most_useless_talent/.json"))
result = JSON.parse(@response)
```

Is there anyway I can get around this?

It is not essential for me to have all the smaller subthreads parsed. Is there a way to set the nesting depth limit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting the max_nesting value:

```
result = JSON.parse(@response, :max_nesting => 100)
```